# SPARK ML, Tuning: Crossvalidation of Multiclass Logistic Regression

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am using Spark 1.6 and I am trying to use a `CrossValidator` to tune a `multiclass Logistic Regression` classifier.

The problem is that the `MultiClassClassificationEvaluator` is not supported by the `CrossValidator` for `multiclass Logistic Regression`.

One solution is to manually re-write the cross-validation in my code, which is something that I prefer not to start before asking if anyone else faced this problem and how it was solved.

Comment: You should do a pull request!

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto thanks, can you elaborate more please?

Comment: I didn't implement the idea yet, I am asking if someone has done such a thing before.